# Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter plugin in a dsl job here the code

```
 parameters {
                  activeChoiceParam('choice1') {
                      description('select your choice')
                      choiceType('RADIO')
                      groovyScript {
                          script("return['aaa','bbb']")
                          fallbackScript('return ["error"]')
                      }
                  }
                  activeChoiceReactiveParam('choice2') {
                      description('select your choice')
                      choiceType('RADIO')
                      groovyScript {
                          script("if(choice1.equals("aaa")){return ['a', 'b']} else {return ['aaaaaa','fffffff']}")
                          fallbackScript('return ["error"]')
                      }
                      referencedParameter('choice1')
                  }
```

and it work's fine what i want now is how to use the activeChoiceReactiveParam  in a jenkinsFile for pipeline job i did that :

```
properties(
    [
            [
                    $class              : 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
                    parameterDefinitions: [
                            [
                                    $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                    choices    : 'aaa\nbbb',
                                    description: 'select your choice : ',
                                    name       : 'choice1'
                            ]
```

but how can i add the choice2 parameter !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using the **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter** i did below and it's working fine !!!

```
node('slave') {
    def choice1
    def choice2

    stage ('Select'){
        choice1 = input( id: 'userInput', message: 'Select your choice', parameters: [ [\$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'aa\nbb', description: '', name: ''] ])
        if(choice1.equals("aa")){
            choice2 = input( id: 'userInput', message: 'Select your choice', parameters: [ [\$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'yy\nww', description: '', name: ''] ])
        }else{
            choice2 = input( id: 'userInput', message: 'Select your choice', parameters: [ [\$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'gg\nkk', description: '', name: ''] ])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

I was in need of the similar solution.
I did not find any related answers/examples specific to Active Choices plugin anywhere in my google search.
With some R & D, finally I was able to get this done for a pipeline project.
Here is the Jenkinsfile code

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Select the Env Name from the Dropdown List', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'Env', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return["Dev","QA","Stage","Prod"]'
                ]
            ]
        ], 
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Select the Server from the Dropdown List', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'Server', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619', 
            referencedParameters: 'Env', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                                return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
                            }
                            else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                                return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"]
                            }
                            else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                                return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"]
                            }
                            else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                                return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
                            }
                        '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
  environment {
         vari = ""
  }
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{
          echo 'Hello'
          echo "${params.Env}"
          echo "${params.Server}"
          if (params.Server.equals("Could not get Environment from Env Param")) {
              echo "Must be the first build after Pipeline deployment.  Aborting the build"
              currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
              return
          }
          echo "Crossed param validation"
        } }
      }
  }
}
```

Even you can use "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" with below definitions and rest of the code, follow as in above example.

```
[$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
            description: 'These are the details in HTML format', 
            name: 'DetailsInHTML', 
            omitValueField: false, 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5633384460832175', 
            referencedParameters: 'Env, Server',
            script: [
                  $class: 'ScriptlerScript',
                  parameters: [[$class: 'org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScriptParameter', name: '', value: '$value']],
                  scriptlerScriptId: 'script.groovy'
        ]
    ]
```

Note: Ensure you have "," delimiter between multiple parameter definition blocks.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a ton @Yogeesh. It helped a lot.
In my case, the requirement was to select multiple instead of one. So, used choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',  and it served the purpose.

```
properties([
parameters([
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
        description: 'Select the Env Name from the Dropdown List', 
        filterLength: 1, 
        filterable: true, 
        name: 'Env', 
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return["Dev","QA","Stage","Prod"]'
            ]
        ]
    ], 
    [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
        description: 'Select Servers', 
        filterLength: 1, 
        filterable: true, 
        name: 'Server', 
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619', 
        referencedParameters: 'Env', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                            return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                            return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                            return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                            return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
                        }
                    '''
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

Comment: How do you read selected values from checkbox? if (Server.equals("devaaa001")) {...}? There could be multiple values selected, so we cannot use "equals".

Comment: So, here in this example, "Env" is the Choice Parameter and  based on the selection, "Server", which is a Cascade Choice Parameter appears.

We can use ${params.Server} to get the value of checkbox selection/s

Comment: what is randomName nameded for?

Answer (score 5):

I made the initial sample work for me.
I had to change `'` for `"` in the return statement `return ["a", "b"]` and `"` by `'` in the script statement `script('   ')`

```
job("MyJob") {
    description ("This job creates ....")
    
    //def targetEnvironment=""
    

    parameters {
         activeChoiceParam('choice1') {
                      description('select your choice')
                      choiceType('RADIO')
                      groovyScript {
                          script('return["aaa","bbb"]')
                          fallbackScript('return ["error"]')
                      }
        }
        activeChoiceReactiveParam('choice2') {
                      description('select your choice')
                      choiceType('RADIO')
                      groovyScript {
                          script(' if(choice1.equals("aaa")) { return ["a", "b"] } else {return ["aaaaaa","fffffff"] } ')
                          fallbackScript('return ["error"]')
                      }
                      referencedParameter('choice1')
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how would i make the reactive param a text box, but with different values depending on the choice?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way that we can put the script logic in a function and call
for example:

```
 [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
        description: 'Select Servers', 
        filterLength: 1, 
        filterable: true, 
        name: 'Server', 
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619', 
        referencedParameters: 'Env', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 
                    ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                            return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                            return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                            return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                            return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
                        }
                    '''
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Define below code in function and call?

```
 if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                            
     return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
     }
                        

else if(Env.equals("QA")){ return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"] } else if(Env.equals("Stage")){ return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"] } else if(Env.equals("Prod")){ return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
properties(
[
        [
                $class              : 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
                parameterDefinitions: [
                        [
                                $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                choices    : 'aaa\nbbb',
                                description: 'select your choice : ',
                                name       : 'choice1'
                        ],
                        [
                                $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                choices    : 'ccc\nddd',
                                description: 'select another choice : ',
                                name       : 'choice2'
                        ]
```

Comment: the choice2 depend on choice1; if the user select choice1 as "aaa" than the choices on choice2 gonna be "cc" or "dd" and if the user select choice1 as "bbb" than the choices on choice2 gonna be "ee" or "rr"