# Jenkinsfile pipeline source an outside file for dynamic parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a unique issue. I have one build system that needs one set of params to start a job and another jenkins server that needs to use the same Jenkinsfile but have a different set of options to select from. Think of it as a jenkins server in region 1 and another in region 2 and they need a different set of options

I have this

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    ENV_NAMES = readFile "/etc/env_list"
  }

  parameters {
    // choices are newline separated
    choice(choices: "${env.ENV_NAMES}", description: 'What Environment?', name: 'env')
  }
}
```

Right now the choice is coming up as `null` but i'd love a way to source an outside file to import those.

I have config management that can place a file with data in it.

So server one would get like

```
env1
env2
env3
```

And server2 would get

```
prod1
prod2
prod3
```

Comment: I hope this answer will help you [exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822045/7726821)

Comment: what does `def choice1` look like?