# Jenkinsfile set parameter dynamically

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I would like to set the parameters default value dynamically that should be depended on condition. Is that possible?

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    string(name: 'test', defaultValue: '', description: 'a string')
stages {
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
          def type = "test"
          if(type == "test") {
            set defaultValue of parameter:test
          }
        }
    }
}}}
```

Comment: what is an example of the condition you have in mind?

Comment: Updated. it will be a string condition. that is not connected to the parameter itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the "default" Jenkins job parameters (e.g. `string`) are set, you can't really change them (assign another value) during a runtime.

But you can use some other plugin(s), e.g. [Active choice](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) that allows you to set more complex parameters and use conditions, scripts and further logic with them (including what you're asking for - value of one is based on another parameter value) - see the plugin description and examples.

Another helpful and answered question with some examples regarding how to use Active choices plugin in pipeline: [Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410204/active-choices-reactive-reference-parameter-in-jenkins-pipeline)