# How to generate code for active choice reactive parameters which I want to use in the Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
Is there any option in Jenkins which will generate the following code snippet for "Active choices reactive parameter. 

parameters {
            choice (name: 'product', choices: ['a','b'])
    //here I want to add active choice reactive parameter.
}
```

I am trying to add one Active choice reactive parameter in the Jenkins file as Parameters. If you have any suggestions or example, please share.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410204/active-choices-reactive-reference-parameter-in-jenkins-pipeline